# Returning nested array with added key=>value

Tags: php, array

This works, but do I have to make a new array, `result`, or is there a way to just insert the field I need into each `$key` of the received parameter `$data`?

Won't this way take up more memory needlessly?

```
function add_tax($data){
            $result = [];
            foreach($data as $product => $details) {
                $details['tax'] = 0;
                $result[$product] = $details;
                } 
            return $result;
          }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something along these lines:

```
function add_tax($data){
        foreach($data as $product => $details) {
            $data[$product]['tax'] = 0;
        }
        return $data;
}
```

EDIT 1:

After a bit more researching on [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) I have come up with the following alternative:

```
function add_tax(&$data) {
    foreach($data as &$details)
        $details['tax'] = 0;
}
```

In reference to Alex L: I apologize, the original answer was rushed. The first snippet was simply a way of answering the question, that yes, it is possible to iterate through `$data` without generating a new variable. Also, to MikeiLL, yes, that would be a waste of memory. This second snippet passes both variables by reference, which does not require any excess usage of memory. It is the most optimal format of this process.

<strike>NOTE: The unset in the function is not exactly necessary, but as your question referenced memory usage, unset breaks the reference and releases that memory.</strike>

EDIT 2:

Due to very strong backing in the comments, I've removed the call to unset (truth be told I'd never use it myself, but wanted to reference it's usage within the function)

Comment: Ya know what would make your answer *even better*? If I knew why you changed what you did, and how that improves the original code!

Comment: that looks very similar to what didn't work the first time, but i'll throw it in there and see. maybe i was missing something.

Comment: Marked in edit addressing Alex L and providing a better code snippet example.

Comment: You don't need the `unset` since `$details` goes out of scope immediately and is not reused.

Comment: Agreed, but without it you're not releasing the memory, you're simply waiting for the garbage collection to take it away. Either way, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Beautiful work. And I think the times the different variations take are interesting (in microtime): Original 8.50821018219E-6 sec
Travis' 1st 8.08984041214E-6 sec
Travis' 2nd 1.72950983047E-6 sec
Travis' 2nd without unset 1.6695690155E-6 sec

Comment: That is a very interesting find. I hadn't even thought to look at the time differences.

Comment: `unset()` does just what it's name says - unset a variable. It does not force immediate memory freeing. PHP's garbage collector will do it when it see fits as `unset()` just decrements the refcount by one. If, and only if, the refcount reaches zero, then PHP knows no more symbols point to the zval, and will free the refcount automatically.

Comment: @TravisWeston - actually my bad - I think we forgot to `return $data;` in the new improved version.

Comment: Nope, because $data is passed as a reference, there's no need to return it.

Comment: Hadn't noticed that. I was calling the function IN the variable assignment like `$order_product = add_tax($this->data['products']);` so `$order_product` was empty. Updated to `$order_product = $this->data['products'];
              add_tax($order_product);`

Comment: @MikeiLL This is why I tend to favor functions without side-effects that return a copy of the data modified appropriately. Both have their uses, however. :)

Answer (score 3):

PHP provides quite a few handy [array-manipulation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). This is a case for [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) which passes each value to a callback and assigns it to the same key in a new array.

```
function add_tax(array $data) {
    return array_map(function ($details) {
        $details['tax'] = 0;
        return $details;
    }, $data);
}
```

This version won't modify the original `$data` array passed to `add_tax`.

How does this differ from writing your own loop using `foreach`? Mostly in style. You'll pay a minor performance penalty switching between system and user space (once for each call to the callback), but you won't notice this unless `$data` is **huge**.

It looks much nicer when the callback returns an immediate expression instead of using one statement to modify and another to return. You can do this here using [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). In fact, this also allows you to refactor `add_tax` into a generic helper function.

```
function extend_arrays(array $arrays, array $additions) {
    return array_map(function ($array) use ($additions) {
        return array_merge($array, $additions);
    }, $arrays);
}

function add_tax($data) {
    return extend_arrays($data, array('tax' => 0));
}

function add_tax_and_shipping($data) {
    return extend_arrays($data, array('tax' => 0, 'shipping' => 0));
}
```

Comment: I'm actually extremely fond of this question now. One of the things I love about programming is how you can solve the same problem infinite numbers of ways. My example was an attempt at removing as much as I could, and giving the simplest version of a solution as I could. This is an example of a more robust, expandable solution.

Comment: This is beautiful. Learned about array maps in Eloquent Javascript. For some reason I'm getting `Undefined variable: additions`, though...

Comment: @MikeiLL Fixed, thanks! I was missing the `use` clause to give the callback access to `$additions`. Probably too much JavaScript lately which doesn't require such nonsense.

Comment: Ahhh. I spent about an hour trying to make the `use`less version work. :) Thank you, professor.

Comment: So in this case, would it have to be an anonymous function to work, and is the parameter referenced by `use` always pulled from an outer function?